# Merge the values of two columns in a Pandas Dataframe applying a function to deduplicate and concatenate

Tags: python, pandas

I'm quite new to pandas but I haven't found any other question that could help me yet. My apologies upfront if this is a clear duplicate question.

I have a csv with 2 columns like this:

```
phones1,phones2
0000,
,1111
2222#3333,3333#4444
5555#6666,777#8888
```

What I want as an end result is a merge operation with some logic to clean up separators (#) and deduplicate values:

```
phones1,phones2,phones_merged
0000,,0000
,1111,1111
2222#3333,3333#4444,2222#3333#4444
5555#6666,777#8888,5555#6666#777#8888
```

I think I need a function to handle this logic to make sure only unique values are kept and that separators are added in a clean way - for example single values don't end up like `#0000#`.

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can call a func on each row and return the unique values joined with '#':

```
In [18]:

def func(x):
    l = []
    r = []
    # handle NaN values
    if pd.notnull(x['phones1']):
        l = x['phones1'].split('#')    
    if pd.notnull(x['phones2']):
        r = x['phones2'].split('#')
    combined = set(l+r)
    return '#'.join(combined)

df['phones_merged'] = df.apply(lambda row: func(row), axis=1)
df
Out[18]:
     phones1    phones2       phones_merged
0       0000        NaN                0000
1        NaN       1111                1111
2  2222#3333  3333#4444      4444#2222#3333
3  5555#6666   777#8888  777#8888#6666#5555
```